# Spring Cache is not cleared on production

Tags: spring, caching

I am using spring cache mechanism with SimpleCacheManager/ConcurrentMapCache.

And I am using a web service to clear the cache and the following is the code .

```
for(String cacheName : cacheManager.getCacheNames()){
        Cache cache =cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
        if(cache!=null){
            cache.clear();
        }
    }
```

When I called this code from a Rest webservice on local vm , I can see its clearing the cache and can see the changes that we done in the database with other service , However on the production environment , the webservice returning 200 status in the logs. but it still shows the old data. 
On production we have 2 servers
We have to restart our application to refresh the cache and get the latest data from the database.

Comment: Wondering what cache manager did you use? 
I know that there are some limitations with  SimpleCacheManager not having eviction contracts. http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M1/reference/html/cache.html

Answer (score 1):

I used to do this creating a void method annotated with @CacheEvict(allEntries=true), this annotation is similar to @CacheRemoveAll from JSR-107.

Something like that:

```
@CacheEvict(allEntries=true)
public void evictAll() {
  // Do nothing
}
```

I know, it's ugly, but works to me.

My two cents, avoid to use the default spring cache manager in production, use a cache manager more sophisticated instead like Guava or EhCache.

Cheers.

Comment: Caffeine is also a good option (Spring deprecated guava in favor of it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175085/why-spring-deprecate-guava-cache-in-official-document)