# Why did Spring framework deprecate the use of Guava cache?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, guava

I want to use spring-cache with guava cache, but I find guava cache has been marked deprecated by spring official document.I wonder to know why, they didn't give some explanations.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider-guava

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider-caffeine; https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/bd7c20eb1cb8a8bf292476dcc34e0fe96325df2b

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Spring project decided to endorse a switch to [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) cache.

Caffeine supersedes
the caching support in the Google Guava library with an actively maintained
Java 8+ version in standalone form.

You can find the relevant issue with the decision on Spring's tracker here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13797

The relevant commit in spring framework github repo is: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/2bf9bc312ed1721b5978f88861c29cffc9ea407c