# Migrating from GuavaCache to EhCache (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, caching, migration, ehcache

I'm trying to change the below method to use EhCache caches rather than Guava caches since Guava caching was removed from Spring 5.0. There doesn't appear to exist any documentation online on how to simply instantiate a EhCacheCache object and pass it into a SimpleCacheManager. How do I achieve this?

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

  @Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {

    GuavaCache a =
        new GuavaCache("a", CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(10000)
            .expireAfterAccess(24, TimeUnit.HOURS).recordStats().build());

    GuavaCache b =
        new GuavaCache("b", CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100)
            .expireAfterAccess(24, TimeUnit.HOURS).recordStats().build());

    GuavaCache c =
        new GuavaCache("c", CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100)
            .expireAfterAccess(24, TimeUnit.HOURS).recordStats().build());

    GuavaCache d =
        new GuavaCache("d", CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(20)
            .expireAfterAccess(24, TimeUnit.HOURS).recordStats().build());

    GuavaCache e =
        new GuavaCache("e", CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100)
            .expireAfterAccess(24, TimeUnit.HOURS).recordStats().build());

    GuavaCache f =
        new GuavaCache("f", CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(10)
            .expireAfterAccess(24, TimeUnit.HOURS).recordStats().build());

    GuavaCache g =
        new GuavaCache("g", CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(5000)
            .expireAfterAccess(24, TimeUnit.HOURS).recordStats().build());

    SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();

    simpleCacheManager.setCaches(
      Arrays.asList(
        a,
        b,
        c,
        d,
        e,
        f,
        g
      )
    );

    return simpleCacheManager;
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess the [intended replacement is actually Caffeine cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175085/why-spring-deprecate-guava-cache-in-official-document)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the way it works. Assuming you will use Ehcache 3.x, it is JSR107 compliant. So you will use `JCacheCacheManager`. Spring-boot will configure it without doing anything when seeing that jcache api is available in the classpath.

In fact, the easiest is usually to let do it and use a `JCacheManagerCustomizer` to add the caches you want. Like below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public JCacheManagerCustomizer cacheManagerCustomizer() {
        return cm -> {
            cm.createCache("a", createConfiguration(100, Duration.ofHours(24)));
        };
    }

    private javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Object, Object> createConfiguration(long size, Duration tti) {
        return Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(
            CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Object.class, Object.class,
                ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(size))
                .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToIdleExpiration(tti))
                .build());
    }
}
```