# Google Guava Cache + Spring example

Tags: spring, caching, guava

I need some example, how to use Guava cache with version of Guava 24.1+ with Spring framework.

I found that there isn't GuavaCacheManager and GuavaCache. Can someone give me the point how to do that? I browse the internet, but I can't find solution.

Thank you.

Comment: It has been replaced by Caffeine, a successor to Guava's cache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why spring deprecate guava cache in official document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175085/why-spring-deprecate-guava-cache-in-official-document)