# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCache

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, guava

Context -

I have a spring boot app and
I updated the `spring-boot-starter-parent` version from `1.5.12.RELEASE` to `2.4.0`

I had this dependency in my pom -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>30.1-android</version>
</dependency>
```

Now when I am running my app, I am getting this error -

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cachesEndpoint' defined in class path resource ...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'guavaCacheManager' defined in class path resource...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'guavaCacheManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cache/guava/GuavaCache ...

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cache/guava/GuavaCache
    at biz.kaar.common.services.cache.TempGuavaCacheConfig.guavaCacheManager(TempGuavaCacheConfig.java:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCache
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Were you able to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by completely removing guava dependency and its references from my project.

If you still need to use caching then try using Caffeine.

Comment: This might be relevant: [Why did Spring framework deprecate the use of Guava cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44175085/525036)

Answer (score 0):

With some more research over the web, I was able to fix the same exception which was occurring in my project by adding spring-context-support to the project.
I did it by adding following dependency to my `build.gradle`:

```
compile("org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.1.7.RELEASE")
```

`spring-context-support` is a library that contains helper methods and classes for configuring the cache.

Here is the blog that I followed:
https://codedevstuff.blogspot.com/2015/07/add-guava-cache-to-spring-boot-to-cache.html